# Long paths between vertices when $G$ has large minimum degree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a 2-connected graph with minimum degree $\delta(G)\geq k$. I want to show that for any two vertices $u$ and $v$ in $G$, I can find a path of length $\geq k$ joining them.

I thought I could prove this by induction on $n=|V(G)|$. For the base case, we see it is true with $n=3$ in $K_3$ (the only nontrivial value to consider is $k=2$).

Now suppose $G$ has $n$ vertices and pick $u$ and $v$. Look at $G'=G-u$, if it is still $2$-connected, then we can apply the IH to get a path $w\dots v$ of length $\geq \delta(G')\geq k-1 $ from some neighbour $w\in N_G(u)$ and then $uw\dots v$ is the desired path.

If $G'$ is no longer $2$-connected however, I'm not sure how to proceed. I am familiar with the block decomposition of graphs into $2$-connected blocks, and I suspect I should reason about $G'$ this way, but I am not sure how to get the path.

Answer (score 0):

Hints.

Your reasoning may well lead to a solution to the problem. We just need to consider the following:

1. We can assume that $\delta(G)\geq3$ (why?).
2. If $G$ is a $2$-connected graph and $\delta(G)\geq3$, then there exists a vertex $x\in V(G)$ such that the graph $G-x$ is also a $2$-connected graph.
   The proof of this statement can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4010349/). See Misha Lavrov's answer.
3. In fact, you only need to have at least one vertex with this property (why?). Your considerations work here.